# How to log testing results to xlsx (Excel) file with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, logs

I have a certain test automation script written in Java with Selenium WebDriver. Currently, I log the testing results to the console and manually copy them to the required document. Is there a way I can log results directly to the xlsx (Excel) file? I use Java programming language with Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can achieve what you want to do.

Basically you want to write the result of your tests in a file.

For this you can use spreadsheet (XLSX) or CSV or even simple text files.

To write your data in a XLSX file you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). Here is a reference [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-data-excel-file-using-apache-poi/) to help with this.

You can use OpenCSV library to write the data to a CSV file. Here is a reference [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-a-csv-file-in-java-using-opencsv/).

Or you can use [Log4j](https://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html) to log all event's and steps executed in the code.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be log everything to file on disk (text .csv file - comma separated values). Then you can import it into excel with few clicks.

[Here is](https://www.baeldung.com/java-csv) some instruction on how to work with .csv.

If you want to generate excel files you could use something more advanced like [Apache POI](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/library/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/).

But that's just the foundation. The proper way would be use something like [log4j](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/log4j-logging/). Once you have static class `Logger`, you can use `log.info()` instead of `System.out.println()`. You can obviously combine this with ideas above (either `.csv` file or `.xls` files). And you only need change implementation of Logger class if you want to switch from `.csv` to `.xls` files

The question is: do you really need Excel file as a place where you log each automated run? After a few months you will have hundreds of files and noone will read them.

Comment: Not really. I think csv will do. Do I understand right that you can open csv with Excel?

Comment: Yes, you can easily "import" .csv to excel (it will put every value separated by comma to separate column).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can log results directly to the xlsx (Excel) file using Apache POI is used. You can check [here](https://poi.apache.org/) for reference.

Following method is used for write data in xlsx file pragmatically after executing each testcase it just updates the status for that test case.

```
private void writeXLSXCellValue(int rowId, String status, int sheetID, String fileName) throws InvalidFormatException {
    try(InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileName)){

        XSSFWorkbook workbook =  new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetID);
        column = sheet.getRow(rowId).getCell(Constant.statusColumnIndexSN);
        column.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        column.setCellValue(status);
        
        try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)){
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
        

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```